# Getting an wrong alert while input is good

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a contact-form with ajax. But the strange thing is that I keep getting the *Fields empty* alert, in a case I fullfilled all fields. 
My JS-code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sendAlert = {
        toastSettings: {
            number: 0
        },
        createAlert: function (alert2, specialClass) {
            if (!specialClass) {
                specialClass = "";
            }

            var toastNumber = sendAlert.toastSettings.number;
            $(".errors").append('' + ' <div class="alert alert-' + specialClass + ' alert-dismissable fade in"> <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' + alert2 + ' </div>');

            sendAlert.toastSettings.number++

        }

    };

    var contact = false;

    $("#submitContact").on("click", function () {
        if (contact == false) {
            contact = true;

            var subject = $('#subject').val();
            var specificsubject = $('#specificsubject').val();
            var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
            var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
            var message = $('#message').val();


            var data = {
                subject: subject,
                specificsubject: specificsubject,
                user_id: user_id,
                email: email,
                first_name: first_name,
                last_name: last_name,
                message: message
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../ajax.php?action=contact",
                async: true,
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {

                    retourzending = false;

                    var err = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    sendAlert.createAlert(err.return, err.type);


                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

My Ajax.php File:

```
$action = htmlentities($_GET['action']); 
switch ($action) {
case "contact":

    $subject         = $_POST['subject'];
    $specificsubject = $_POST['specificsubject'];
    $first_name      = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name       = $_POST['last_name'];
    $user_id         = $_POST['user_id'];
    $email           = $_POST['email'];
    $message         = $_POST['message'];
    $ipadres         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (strlen($subject) < 1 || strlen($specificsubject) < 1 || strlen($first_name) < 1 || strlen($last_name) < 1 || strlen($email) < 1 || strlen($message) < 1) {

        $err['data'] = array("status" => "failed", "type" => "danger", "return" => "Niet alle verplichte velden zijn correct ingevuld.");

    } else {

        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';

        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dbname", $username, $password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO supportcontact (subject, specificsubject, first_name, last_name, userid, email, message, ipadres) VALUES ('" . $subject . "','" . $specificsubject . "','" . $first_name . "','" . $last_name . "','" . $user_id . "','" . $email . "','" . $message . "','" . $ipadres . "')";

            if ($dbh->query($sql)) {

                $err['data'] = array("status" => "success", "type" => "success", "return" => "Bedankt voor je bericht! We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met u op.");

            } else {


                $err['data'] = array("status" => "failed", "type" => "danger", "return" => "Oeps. Er is iets fout gegaan.");

            }

            $dbh = null;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    $err['endpoint'] = json_encode($err['data'], $options = 0);
    exit($err['endpoint']);

    break;}
```

My HTML code:

```
<div style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;" class="errors"></div>
<label for="subject" class="">Onderwerp <sup style="color:red">*</sup></label>
<select id="subject">
    <option selected disabled value="">Selecteer een onderwerp…</option>
    <option value="support">Support</option>
    <option value="sales">Sales</option>
    <option value="technisch">Technisch</option>
    <option value="overig">Overige</option>
</select>
<input class="form-input" type="text" id="specificsubject" placeholder="Specifiek onderwerp">
<input class="form-input" type="text" id="user_id" placeholder="Klantnummer">
<input class="form-input" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Emailadres">
<input class="form-input" type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="Voorletter(s)">
<input class="form-input" type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Achternaam">
<textarea class="contact_form_textarea" name="contacteditor" id="message" placeholder=""></textarea>
<input style="float:right;" class="grey" id="submitContact" type="submit" value="Verzenden">
```

And now is my question: What am I doing wrong thats giving me the 'wrong' error while all inputs are fullfilled. In my opinion I did all things correctly, but the interwebs does not think so I guess..

UPDATE:
Network in Google Chrome gives the following:

```
subject:technisch
specificsubject:ads
user_id:asd
email:asd
first_name:asd
last_name:asd
message:
```

The problem is that the Message area (CKEDITOR) does not post the info.

UPDATE 2.0

```
var message = CKEDITOR.instances.message.getData();
```

With de code above my thing worked. Only saving to db is still an issue.

Comment: Well, the first thing you could do is to try before setting `$err['endpoint']`-  to `print_r($err['data']);` to be sure what data it holds.

Comment: And you could replace `exit($err['endpoint'])` with `echo $err['endpoint']; exit();`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos I did your steps, in my console I get the following:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (general.js?version=4:94)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)`

Comment: Try changing `json_encode($err['data'], $options = 0);` to `json_encode($err['data'], true);`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos you mean like this?
`print_r($err['data']) = json_encode($err['data'], true);
        echo $err['endpoint']; exit(); `

Comment: `print_r()` is like `echo` but you can see the data of an array..like this -> `$err['endpoint'] = json_encode($err['data'], true); echo $err['endpoint']; exit();`

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos if I put that code in, the console shows like nothing

Comment: Does all yourhtml form elements have ids? Because you are accessing the values by the ids. If possible, put up your html code as well.

Comment: @T.Shah Added HTML.

Comment: I commented out your database connectivity part in ajax.php and things work ok. I think your database connection has problems and - echo $e->getMessage(); - this is getting fired and giving you error.  Also the very first line in the same you have a typo - $ is missing in front of action - check that too.